# Erro no método de transformar arquivo de texto com nós em AVL ser usado em interface gráfica

Tags: java

A ideia de gerar a interface gráfica será através de um arquivo em python para isso tenho que gerar um arquivo de texto no formato seguinte:

```
4  [2] [6]
2 [1]  [3]
6  [5] [8] 
1  [] []
3  []  [] 
5  [] []                 
8  [7] [9] 
7 []  [] 
9 []  []
```

Bom, com isso temos que fazer a função `savetofile`. Ela está dando os seguintes erros:

```
AvlTree.java:188: error: cannot find symbol
    if (ptraiz==0) return;
        ^
  symbol:   variable ptraiz
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:190: error: cannot find symbol
    LinkedList<nd> list = new LinkedList<nd>();
               ^
  symbol:   class nd
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:190: error: cannot find symbol
    LinkedList<nd> list = new LinkedList<nd>();
                                         ^
  symbol:   class nd
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:192: error: cannot find symbol
        fila.push(ptraiz);
                  ^
  symbol:   variable ptraiz
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:192: error: cannot find symbol
        fila.push(ptraiz);
        ^
  symbol:   variable fila
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
        while (!fila.empty()) {
                ^
  symbol:   variable fila
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:198: error: cannot find symbol
            nd q = fila.front();
            ^
  symbol:   class nd
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:198: error: cannot find symbol
            nd q = fila.front();
                   ^
  symbol:   variable fila
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:201: error: cannot find symbol
                fila.push(q.esq);
                ^
  symbol:   variable fila
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:206: error: cannot find symbol
                fila.push(q.dir);
                ^
  symbol:   variable fila
  location: class AvlTree
AvlTree.java:211: error: cannot find symbol
            fila.pop();
            ^
  symbol:   variable fila
  location: class AvlTree
11 errors
```

alguem poderia ajudar

```java
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class AvlTree {  
       private AvlNode root = null;  

       public AvlTree( ) {  
           root = null;  
       }  

       public void clear() {  
           root = null;  
       }  
       public boolean isEmpty() {  
           return root == null;  
       }  

       public AvlNode getRootNode (){  
           return root;  
       }  

       /** Retorna a altura da árvore */  
       private static int height( AvlNode t ) {  
           return t == null ? -1 : t.height;  
       }  

        /** 
        * Retorna o maior valor ente lhs e rhs. 
        */  
       private static int max( int lhs, int rhs ) {  
           return lhs > rhs ? lhs : rhs;  
       }  

       /** Retorna o fator de balanceamento da árvore com raiz t */   
       private int getFactor (AvlNode t) {  
           return height( t.left ) - height( t.right );  
       }  

       public boolean insert (int x) {  
           root = insert (x, root);  
           return true;  
       }  

       private AvlNode insert (int x, AvlNode t) {  
           if( t == null )  
               t = new AvlNode( x, null, null );  
           else if( x<t.key ) t.left = insert( x, t.left );  
           else if( x>t.key) t.right = insert( x, t.right );  
           t = balance (t);  
           return t;  
       }  

       public AvlNode balance (AvlNode t) {  
           if ( getFactor(t) == 2 ) {  
                   if (getFactor (t.left)>0) t = doRightRotation( t );  
                   else t = doDoubleRightRotation( t );  
           }  
           else if ( getFactor(t) == -2 ) {  
                   if ( getFactor(t.right)<0 ) t = doLeftRotation( t );  
                   else t = doDoubleLeftRotation( t );  
           }  
           t.height = max( height( t.left ), height( t.right ) ) + 1;  
           return t;  
       }  

       /** Faz Rotação simples a direita */  
       private static AvlNode doRightRotation( AvlNode k2 ) {  
           AvlNode k1 = k2.left;  
           k2.left = k1.right;  
           k1.right = k2;  
           k2.height = max( height( k2.left ), height( k2.right ) ) + 1;  
           k1.height = max( height( k1.left ), k2.height ) + 1;  
           return k1;  
       }  

       /** Rotação simples à esquerda */  
       private static AvlNode doLeftRotation( AvlNode k1 ) {  
           AvlNode k2 = k1.right;  
           k1.right = k2.left;  
           k2.left = k1;  
           k1.height = max( height( k1.left ), height( k1.right ) ) + 1;  
           k2.height = max( height( k2.right ), k1.height ) + 1;  
           return k2;  
       }  

       /** Rotação dupla à direita */  
       private static AvlNode doDoubleRightRotation( AvlNode k3 ) {  
           k3.left = doLeftRotation( k3.left );  
           return doRightRotation( k3 );  
      }  

       /** Rotação dupla à esquerda */  
       private static AvlNode doDoubleLeftRotation( AvlNode k1 ) {  
           k1.right = doRightRotation( k1.right );  
           return doLeftRotation( k1 );  
       }  

       public AvlNode search(int el) {  
           return search(root,el);  
       }  
       protected AvlNode search(AvlNode p, int el) {  
           while (p != null) {  
               /* se valor procuradp == chave do nó retorna referência ao nó */   
               if (el==p.key) return p;  
               /* se valor procurado < chave do nó, procurar na sub-árvore esquerda deste nó */  
               else if (el<p.key) p = p.left;  
               /* se valor procurado > chave do nó, procurar na sub-árvore direita deste nó */  
               else p = p.right;  
           }  
           // caso chave não foi achada, retorna null  
           return null;  
       }  

       public void inorder() {  
           inorder(root);  
       }  
       protected void inorder(AvlNode p) {  
           if (p != null) {  
                inorder(p.left);  
                System.out.print(p.key+" - ");  
                inorder(p.right);  
           }  
       }  

       public void preorder() {  
           preorder(root);  
       }  
       protected void preorder(AvlNode p) {  
           if (p != null) {  
                System.out.print(p.key + " ");  
                preorder(p.left);  
                preorder(p.right);  
           }  
       }  

       public void postorder() {  
           postorder(root);  
       }  

       protected void postorder(AvlNode p) {  
           if (p != null) {  
                postorder(p.left);  
                postorder(p.right);  
                System.out.print(p.key + " ");  
           }  
       }  

   protected AvlNode searchFather (int el) {  
       AvlNode p = root;  
       AvlNode prev = null;  
       while (p != null && !(p.key==el)) {  // acha o nó p com a chave el  
           prev = p;                             
           if (p.key<el)  
                 p = p.right;  
           else p = p.left;  
       }  
       if (p!=null && p.key==el) return prev;  
       return null;  
   }  

   /* método de autoria de Leonardo Zandoná - 2006/2 */  
   public void displayTree() {  
    if (isEmpty()){  
        System.out.println("Árvore vazia!");  
        return;  
    }             
    String separator = String.valueOf("  |__");  
    System.out.println(this.root.key+"("+root.height+")");  
    displaySubTree(root.left,  separator);  
    displaySubTree(root.right, separator);  
}  
private void displaySubTree(AvlNode node, String separator) {  

    if (node != null) {  

        AvlNode father = this.searchFather(node.key);  
        if (node.equals(father.left) == true) {  
            System.out.println(separator+node.key+"("+node.height+")"+" (ESQ)");  
        }else{  
            System.out.println(separator+node.key+"("+node.height+")"+" (DIR)");  
        }             
        displaySubTree(node.left,  "     "+separator);  
        displaySubTree(node.right, "     "+separator);  
    }  
}  

         public void savetofile(OutputStream fnome) {
    if (ptraiz==0) return;

    LinkedList<nd> list = new LinkedList<nd>();

        fila.push(ptraiz);
   //     ofstream out(fnome);
    //    fnome= new FileOutputStream("saida.txt");
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fnome);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        while (!fila.empty()) {
            nd q = fila.front();
              bw.write(q.chave +" ");
            if (q.esq != 0) {
                fila.push(q.esq);
                bw.write(" ["+q.esq.chave  +"] ");
            } else
            bw.write(" [] ");
            if (q.dir != 0) {
                fila.push(q.dir);
                bw.write(" ["+q.dir.chave+"] ");
            } else
                    bw.write(" [] ");
                    bw.newLine();
            fila.pop();
    }
    bw.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

A mensagem de erro `cannot find symbol` significa que você tentou acessar uma variável que não foi definida em lugar algum. Ou um parâmetro, ou um tipo. No seu caso, há 3 nomes que o programa não conseguiu resolver: `nd`, `fila` e `ptraiz`.

`nd` se não me engano é uma classe, certo? Tirando o fato de ir contra a convenção do Java criar classes iniciadas em letras minúsculas (fica mais difícil saber que se trata de uma classe), seu problema deve ser que você definiu a classe `nd` em um outro arquivo (provavelmente `nd.java`) mas esqueceu de **importá-la** no seu `AvlTree.java` (que deve estar em um pacote diferente, aliás). Se `nd.java` está no pacote `meu.pacote` importe-o dessa forma no `AvlTree.java`:

```
import meu.pacote.nd;
```

Se ele está em pacote nenhum (i.e. no pacote padrão/*default*), então talvez ele não possa ser importado, e você terá que colocá-lo num pacote.

Quanto a `fila` e `ptraiz`, certifique-se de que essas variáveis estejam acessíveis ao seu método em `AvlTree` (passando-as como argumento pro método, ou incluindo-as dentre as variáveis de instância do objeto).